# How to sort mongoose populated array by a value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I get user schema ads by populating ads like this :

```
let user;
    try {
        user = await User.findOne({ _id: id }).populate('ads').sort([ [ 'date', -1 ] ]);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Could not post user : ' + e);
        return next(e);
    }

    res.json({
        ads: user.ads
    });
```

But the sort doesn't work .

How can I sort ads by their date value ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate), you can do it with:

```
User.findOne({ _id: id }).populate({
  path: 'ads',
  options: { sort: { 'date': -1 } }
})
```

More infos about other options can be found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.populate).